# Python Instance definition

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have confusion about Instance VS object. What is the difference between an instance and an object? or both same? I have searched in web, but not confident so far.. If possible answer in Tamil or English.

Answer (score 0):

The class = the blue print. The Object is an actual thing that is built based on the ‘blue print’ (like the house). An instance is a virtual copy (but not a real copy) of the object.

Check out this forum => https://www.codecademy.com/forum_questions/558cd3fc76b8fe06280002ce

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the following.

Lets say you have a class like this:

```
class car():

def __init__(self, color):
    self.color = color 


def show_color(self):
    print(self.color)
```

The Class is basically the blueprint for the object
An instance is a unique copy of that Class that is representing that Object.
So we have the class car.
We create an instance like this:

```
yellow_car = car("yellow")
```

Now we have an `instance` of the `object` `car` that was created with the blueprint of the `class car`.